# how to sanitize json reply from Microsoft Flow HTTP request

Tags: c#, json, httpresponse, asp.net-core-3.1, power-automate

in my App when I send parameters on my Microsoft Flows HTTP request it sends a reply that on the JSON string below is my code. how can I get the value of the status?
Am I lacking something to get the "No data met the criteria" value?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SendNameAge()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                // Create new instance of Person
                Person person = new Person
                {
                    Name = SD.HTTPName, 
                    Age = SD.HTTPAge    
                };

                var personJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);   
                var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(personJSON);    
                var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer); 
                byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"); 

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(SD.ApiUri);    
                var response = await client.PostAsync(SD.ApiUri, byteContent);  

                string jsonstatus = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                return Ok(response);
            }
        }
```

I need to get the "No data met the criteria" response from the HTTP request
[image]

This is from the Postman test

[image]

Comment: Deserialize it? E.g., `string status = JArray.Parse(jsonstatus)[0]["Status"].ToString();`

Comment: @Jimi OMG! it works in just 1 line of code (-_-)... thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome :) BTW, that `.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` is not a good thing.

Comment: ow.. what do you suggests to use? :)

Comment: What you did in the line of code right above.

Comment: ow, I will try that one. I'm just new in working with JSON file.. thank you, Sir!

Comment: Well, it's not about JSON serialization, it's about blocking `async` code. Avoid.